# html <select> events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select in my html, is formed by AJAX function. That function must called when user clicking on arrow off dropdown list. The w3c said what select tags have next events: onfocus, onblur, onchange. None of these events does not correspond to what i need. What can i do except using jquery plugins?

Comment: You just got yourself in a XY problem. (You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y). There's no 'arrowClicking' event, even with jQuery, and no way to simulate that AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have an onclick as well. Just try it.

Comment: that works in all browsers except ie6 because it not in w3c html standart

Comment: Awesome .. well, I guess you can't then .. or just ditch IE6? :D